# How do you set attribute selected for element and remove attributes from rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The thing that i'm trying to accomplish is when the option is selected by user, it should add dom attribute "selected" to that element. And remove "selected" attribute from other listed elements.

```
<select id="tSelect" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="Inlook">Inlook</option>
    <option value="Metallium">Metallium</option>
    <option value="Ossmet">Ossmet</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#tSelect").change(function(){
    $("#tSelect option:selected").removeAttr('selected');
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#tSelect option[value="' + val + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

This is my code so far, but it seems not to be working.

Comment: Why do you need it? There is already `selected` property.

Comment: this is exactly what a selectbox does. if you select one, the others aren't selected anymore...

Comment: It automatically remove `selected` property from other options when you select one option!

Comment: I need the full page DOM with correct "selected" properties for generating .pdf. When simply selecting option it wont be shown in DOM.

Comment: This code makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "*it wont be shown in DOM*".  What do you use to access and view DOM?

Comment: $("#div").html() will be passed to the script which generates the .pdf

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your comment makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @user1936204 Good one. I'm sure you'll go far.

Comment: There is a `selected` attribute and `selected` property. Just because the `selected` attribute doesn't change in the DOM, doesn't mean that the `selected` property also doesn't change when you change the selected option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="tSelect" class="form-control input-sm">
<option value="0">Inlook</option>
<option value="1">Metallium</option>
<option value="2">Ossmet</option>
</select>

$("#tSelect").change(function(e) {
var val = $(this).val();
$(this.options).removeAttr('selected');
$('select>option:eq('+val+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Here is the script i made and using right now.

Thanks @dfsq your answer was very helpful :)

Comment: Your script is incorrect and will not work once you change option values.

Comment: It works great, i did little modification so the option values are now numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Now, when I got why you need this here is possible solution. Note that shenanigans with `x-selected` custom attribute are needed because you can't set/remove `selected` attribute without interfering with actual option selection. So you can set dummy attribute and just replace it with real when you get select HTML.

```js
$("#tSelect").change(function() {
    $(this.options).removeAttr('x-selected');
    $(this).find(':selected').attr('x-selected', 'selected');

    var outerHTML = this.outerHTML.replace(/x-selected/g, 'selected');
    alert(outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="tSelect" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="Inlook">Inlook</option>
    <option value="Metallium">Metallium</option>
    <option value="Ossmet">Ossmet</option>
</select>
```